# Google Map Center set user current position

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to make marker moving and get lat lng. My code works correctly.but Now I want to set my map center as my current location. I am trying with geo location code but when i add  getCurrentPosition then map not showing.

my moving marker map code is

```
 var marker, map;

      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.871963457471786,10.689697265625);      

                var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        } 
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });

      }
      $(function() {
        initialize();

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {    
            var lat=event.latLng.lat();
            var lng=event.latLng.lng();
            $('#latlng').val(lat+', '+lng); 
          marker.animateTo(event.latLng);
        });
      }); 

   <input type="text" id="latlng" size="40" /><br />
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough...

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      //handle no geolocation
    });
```

Just make sure you run this after the map is created.

By the way this is from Google Maps docs.